# Is the hypothesized technology zenith in star wars universe plausible?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars, technology rarely varies from era to era. Stuff 3,000 years before the original movies and then over 100 years after the original movies is about the same. No advances or progression in technology. Fans have theorizes that technology hit a peak and never changed. Is that a plausible explanation. Could technology just peter out?

Comment: While I'm completely astonished that this was closed as "off-topic" (seriously, people?); there was a previous SE question whose answer conclusively demonstrated that the technology wasn't as static as it appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is examined in detail on TV Tropes (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MedievalStasis).

Out-of-universe, it's this way because the Star Wars series is fundamentally about characters and plot, not technology; compare Star Trek, where a little "technology porn" was a component of the setting, a reflection of Roddenberry's techno-optimism.  Also, Star Wars is at heart a *fantasy* series, with some science fiction trappings.  Eternal technological stasis has been accepted in fantasy for a long time, reflecting the timelessness of myths.  Much of the fantasy genre predates the modern concept of progress, after all, and when Tolkien essentially re-invented it for the modern day, he embraced this theme of eternal medieval England because it fit with his Luddite leanings.

In-universe, it's not inconceivable that physical limits will eventually bring technological advancement to an end.  Moore's law may be starting to hit the wall, for example.  I certainly wouldn't bet on computers not progressing any further, but one can see how clock speeds and transistor sizes can't keep going up and down respectively, forever.  Also, while we've seen dramatic and ever-accelerating technological progress in the last 250 years, there have been periods of human history where technology was essentially stopped for thousands of years.  Granted, this usually occurred because the human population was small and fragmented; with populations in the hundreds of billions and faster-than-light communication, the Star Wars galaxy should be bustling with innovation.

Specific governments have occasionally tried to hold back progress; I won't name particular times and places, because it's a prickly subject.  The Empire is said to have deliberately held back or even sabotaged certain Republic-era technologies, like the holonet, so that could be a factor.  (Out-of-universe, of course, Lucas simply didn't anticipate all the technology us Earthlings would invent in the 30 years between movies; few people did).